# Custom rewrites on HTACCESS

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I already have a htaccess file on my website which do the following job. It turns **example.com/steve** to **example.com/profile.php?id=steve** for example.

It means that urls like **example.com/something** should go to profile.

Now, I have a problem with removing .php extensions from other urls of website.

For example **example.com/home** should open **homepage** but it thinks it is a profile with name "home".

How can we do both?

my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$

# Forcing HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1&amount=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Will there, except /home, be more (how many?) exceptions that should not go to profile?

Comment: All of the pages in the website must be exception. About 15 pages.